# C++ Referencing a boost::thread from its thread function

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, this

I'm working with boost threads and I need to reference a thread from its thread function so I can store it in a map with its corresponding thread id. The main idea is that I will be using another thread to gather thread stats by querying the proc table, so I cant use `boost::this_thread::get_id()`. I need to store the thread so I can call interrupts and joins on specific threads.

The following insert statement doesn't work, but I would have expected this or &this to reference the thread.

Thread function:

```
workerFunc(){
    std::string tid;
    tid=boost::lexical_cast<string>(syscall(SYS_gettid));
    threadMap.insert(pair<std::string,boost::thread>(tid,this));
}
```

Currently I have the parent make the insert but wait for the thread to get its thread id, but that is not what a want.

How can I store the thread/a pointer to the thread without using the parent?

Comment: When you say the following statement doesnt work, what do you mean? It doesnt compile? Or it doesnt store the pair as expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using a functor instead of a function, you can add state to it.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't directly pass `thread` object to the function (or functor) that you pass to `thread`'s constructor. It kind of "the egg or the chicken".

The entity that should fill this map is the manager, which creates these thread objects. And why do you have to "wait for the thread to get its thread id"? I don't see such a requirement in the documentation - `get_id()` is applicable to any "thread of execution", i.e. non-detached `thread`.

Comment: I'm using `SYS_gettid`, which I can only call from inside the thread and since I'm using the parent to store the threads I need to wait for each thread to get its `SYS_gettid` before I can store the thread in a map.

Comment: @user1668886 I see. So, you have to wait anyway, in any approach - because the object creation and the start of the physical thread happen asynchronously.